# how to make blank textbox equal 0

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textbox below which is created through this code:

```
$('#txtWeight').each( function() {

     var $this = $(this);
     var $weightText = $("<input type='text' class='txtWeightRow' maxlength='5' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'/>").attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
                     .attr('value',$this.val())

    $weight.append($weightText);

    });
```

What I want to know is that how is it suppose to be written that if the textbox is blank, then it should have a hidden value of 0?

Below is code which does the calculation between 100 and the number entered in the textbox:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
   var totalweight = totalmarks;
   $("#qandatbl td.weight input").each(function (i, elm){
        totalweight = totalweight - parseInt($(elm).val(), 10);
    });

    $("#total-weight").text(totalweight);
}
```

td.weight input is the textbox.

totalmarks = 100.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden value"? By definition, textbox values are not hidden. You have to be more clear about what you want. Do you want it to show up as "0" when you submit to the server? (if so, do it on server side). Do you want it to show up as "0" from the perspective of another javascript function? (if so, do it inside that function).

Comment: I want a blank textbox to equal 0 but do not show the figure 0 in the textbox, that is what I meant. I want it so lets say user enter in the number 3 and then deletes the number and leaves the textbox blank and click away, then the value is back to 0.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. See my answer. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Or maybe I'm still misunderstanding you. If you want the box to remain blank, that's fine, just leave it blank. Then just *treat* a blank value as "0" in whatever method you are using the value for. Understand what I mean?

Comment: Right I have a figure of 100. Now whatever number i enter in the textbox, it takes away the number entered in the textbox from 100 E.g If I enter in 5 then 100 - 5 = 95. Problem is that if the textbox is empty, it display NaN instead of 100 because the textbox is blank meaning it has no value. That is why I want the blank textbox to have a value of 0 but don't display the 0

Comment: Then you should treat it as zero in the function that does the subtraction. Show *that* code, since that's where you need to make the cahnge.

Comment: See my new answer for an example.

Comment: Hi, Include the full code in the question edit which shows the full code of the textbox and the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that does the subtraction, you can treat an empty value as 0 by using the `Number()` constructor (a typecast). Like this:

```
var $result = 100 - Number($('#txtWeight').val());
```

Then it doesn't matter what is in the textbox, the subtraction will work. If the value in the textbox is not a number (e.g. an empty string) it will be treated as the number zero, and the result of the subtraction will be 100 (not NaN).

In your code, just use `Number()` instead of `parseInt()`:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    var totalweight = totalmarks;
    $("#qandatbl td.weight input").each(function (i, elm){
        totalweight = totalweight - Number($(elm).val());
    });

    $("#total-weight").text(totalweight);
}
```

If you want just to avoid decimal numbers, you can even do parseInt after the Number (i.e. `totalweight = totalweight - parseInt(Number($(elm).val()), 10);`).

Comment: Hi, Include the full code in the question edit which shows the full code of the textbox and the calculation

Comment: @user1181690, Okay, I just updated my answer to show how to do it in your code.

Comment: Thank You, that wroked well :)

Answer (score 0):

On your form submit, you could just check to see if it has a value...

```
var myVal = $('#txtWeight').val();
myVal = myVal == '' ? 0 : myVal;
```

Comment: Hi, Include the full code in the question edit which shows the full code of the textbox and the calculation

Answer (score 0):

Conveniently, the result of coercing an empty string to a number is `0`.  So, wherever you need to use the value of the textbox, just coerce it to a number first (by using the `+` operator):

```
var weight = +$("#txtWeight").val();
```

This will give you `0` for empty strings, or whatever number is entered for other numbers.  Since you are preventing non-number keys from being pressed, the only thing you need to worry about is alternative input methods such as copy/paste or drag/drop.

**Edit:** Looking at your `calculateTotal()` function, all you really need to do is to get rid of your call to `parseInt()`.  The substraction operator (`-`) in your expression is already implicitly coercing the value to a number.  It's getting messed up because `parseInt` is returning `NaN`.

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var totalweight = totalmarks;
    $("#qandatbl td.weight input").each(function (i, elm) {
        totalweight -= elm.value;
    });

    $("#total-weight").text(totalweight);   
}
```

Note, I also shortened your expression from `x = x - n` to `x -= n`, and skipped creating a jQuery object just to read the `value` property.

Comment: Hi, Include the full code in the question edit which shows the full code of the textbox and the calculation

Comment: @user1181690 - I've updated my answer to incorporate your `calculateTotal()` function.